# why we say"over in the meadow"? meanning | grammar

Tags: grammar

what is the grammar of "over in"?I can not understand.I know over means being up to something,but what about "over in "?

Comment: @JHCL It's different "over"..I think..

Comment: What do you think the difference is? (And why do you think *over* means "being up to something"?)

Comment: No, it's not a different *over.* It's the same meaning as "over there" -- a distance away.